# Ubuntu 20.04 Autoinstall, Cloud-Init and Subiquity

Tags: 20.04, cloud-init, subiquity

I'm PXE booting the ISO and using the new Subiquity installer.  I've got a working autoinstall setup/config with a working user-data file.

What's not working is that I have an `ansible:` section that the autoinstall completely ignores.  The ansible module is supported in the cloud-init reference but not in the Ubuntu server autoinstall reference.

What I am wondering is if I am being stupid by assuming that the autoinstall options support all of the cloud-init modules?

Ubuntu Server Auto-Install Reference - https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/autoinstall-reference
Cloud-Init Module Reference - https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/modules.html#

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a difference between autoinstall and cloud-init. I also got mislead.
Here's a small hint from the autoinstall documentation:
"Note that autoinstall is processed by Subiquity (not cloud-init)". So you can't expect from autoinstall processing cloud-init parameters.